# Sum non-missing columns in dataframe by row

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to calculate the total number of non-missing columns from a selection of a dataframe. I can achieve it using the following code:

```
data %>%
  select(
    Rftrialnum,
    Rfdaterando,
    OID1treatmentcycle,
    OID2treatmentcycle,
    OID3treatmentcycle,
    OID4treatmentcycle,
    OID5treatmentcycle,
    OID6treatmentcycle,
    Eoipptpreg,
    Eoicompletedoi
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    count_cycle = sum(across(ends_with("treatmentcycle"), ~ !is.na(.)))
  )
```

Which sums the number of non missing values from `OID1treatmentcycle` to `OID6treatmentcycle` and saves as a new variable `cycle_count`. However, it uses `rowwise()`, which is very slow considering the dataframe has thousands of rows. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: the Base R function `rowSums` should be much faster in this case

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three variants.

Considering a 10 x 3 example dataframe `d`:

```
d <- structure(list(A = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L), 
    B = c(5L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L), C = c(1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

1. with base R:

```
d$na_count <-  d |> apply(1, \(xs) sum(is.na(xs)))
```

2. with `dplyr`, mutating rowwise (your version):

```
d |>  rowwise() |> mutate(na_count = sum(across(everything(), ~ !is.na(.))))
```

3. using dplyr's `c_across` for cross-column calculations:

```
count_na = \(xs) sum(is.na(xs)) ## helper function
d |>  rowwise() |> mutate(na_count = count_na(c_across(everything())))
```

speed (median of 100 reps, as measured with {microbenchmark})

```
base R:    101.95 microseconds
`across`:   28.06 milliseconds
`c_across`: 18.77 milliseconds
```

So you can gain some speed with `c_across` but base R is 180 times faster, as @[Leon Samson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11856430/leon-samson) pointed out.

Comment: Be wary using `c_across(everything())` if your `df` data object has mixed variable types as `c_across()` will throw an error. Better to figure out the data types involved (e.g. `lapply(df, class) %>% unlist() %>% unique()`) and make separate vectors to represent each data type e.g. for integer or numeric types it'd be `numeric_cols <- sapply(df, is.numeric) %>% which() %>% as.vector()` and then using `select(all_of(numeric_cols))`